# How to make grass respond to an object hitting them

Tags: animation, physics

How can i make the grass bend when this cube hits it?

Here's the picture:

[image]

Comment: there is a link at the bottom left of your question to [edit] the original post. Use that to add information and corrections. Also please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files. To add images use the tools available on this site: Please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Comment: @Tucker Should grass stand up after the hit or should it lay on the ground after it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

Whole process is very easy. You will only need to make your grass object as **Cloth** or **Soft Body** (with **Weight Paint**) then **Convert Particle System** to mesh and delete **Particle Emitter** as it will not longer be needed. Then add to your Cube **Collision**.

First of all you will need to choose if you want to use **Cloth** or **Soft Body**. Quick test shows me that **Cloth** simulation is fairly faster, but **Soft Body** will give you probably more options, as **Plastics**, **Edge Stiffness** and such.

Secondly I don't know why (and maybe someone can correct me) when your object is in **Particle System** simulation works, but **Pinning/Soft Body Goal** won't. Maybe it's a bug or maybe there is an explanation.

> Note: Below steps could vary from your scene setup so don't take them
>   as granted. I will point out most important settings and you could
>   tweak them for your needs.

### Steps:

**Grass strand.**

[image: Grass]

1. You will need to **Weight Paint** your grass strand. Red is stiff, green is... less stiff. You can experiment with this as you like to make grass really soft or hard.
2. Add to your object **Cloth Simulation**. I have used settings as you can see on the image. Most important things here are:

   - **Mass** - it should be really low, higher will make grass to lay on the ground,
   - **Pinning** - from **Weight Paint**, it will keep grass strong at the bottom and weak at the top, or not if you painted it differently,
   - **Velocity** - how fast grass will return to base position,
   - **Cloth Collision** - check also **Self Collision**, there are lots of them so it will make simulation more realistic.

**Particle Emitter.**

Nothing special here, only after setting your grass go to **Modifier Tab** and **Convert Particles** then delete **Particle Emitter**.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: This works fine for me in 2.79 but your blend file doesn't work in 2.8 any idea?

Comment: @Wes yes, this is because Blender 2.80 introduced new Cloth simulations. You can read about it here: https://code.blender.org/2017/06/improvements-to-the-cloth-simulator/ I can try to make it work with new settings but you should be able to tweak it properly.

Comment: I got it working for this particular use case (your file) by turning off self collision. However it doesn't help me for the use case I was hoping to solve when downloading your file. I'm finding the cloth/hair simulation a bit broken at the scales I'm trying.  A hair emitter just with hair particles falling onto a collision surface causes some crazy effects. Thank you I'm not disputing your comment. Also thanks for the link.

Comment: @wes I didn't had time and reason to test the new simulator, but first quick attempts wasn't very appealing to me also. You can drop your file somewhere and post a link, I'll try to think of something if you want.