# How to make a realistic droplet drop on leaf?

Tags: cloth-simulation, soft-body

I would like to have this to be so that the leaf is really getting the weight of the droplet and bending because of the weight of the droplet. And that the droplet really drags on the leaf before falling. So, in other words, as realistic as possible. How to do that?

[image]

[image]

Wow, got this by editing the .blend of @CLR's

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Softbody and a cloth object with collision enabled to produce feedback beween the simulations.
https://gyazo.com/f513d99f530abdf3e178121fdb298b02

[image]

Comment: Wooow this is so good!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Hello and welcome. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image and a file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Answer (score 1):

here's one possible concept behind the lead that bends when a force (object + gravity) impacts it:
[enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86471/how-to-make-grass-respond-to-an-object-hitting-them). You need to play a lot with "cloth" and "soft-body" settings.

Enable collision on the "water drop" and on the "cloth":

[image]

Comment: But in that example the collision object is animated, not simulated, like I would like to have